# Is there a gl*TexStorage* equivalent to glCompressedTexImage*

Tags: opengl, textures

I have been using gl*TexImage* functions to create textures and then heard of glTexStorage* that is supposed to be better and is introduced in the latest standards.

But the problem is that I can't seem to find an equivalent to glCompressedTexImage2D(...) in terms of gl*TexStorage.

I've only found 2 references on an IRC chat to these supposedly equivalent functions while searching. ([here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/dri-log/?channel=dri-devel&date=2016-05-20) and [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/dri-log/?channel=dri-devel&date=2016-05-15))

Do these equivalent functions even exist ? And if they don't, why don't they exist ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems glTexStorage* functions do support compressed formats just by specifying the correct "internal format" parameter, i.e. there is a list of flags (GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT, etc...) that handle such compressed textures. You can find the list [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D#Description).